# Outlook: Move item from me to a folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I create reminders for myself by sending an email to me and moving them to a folder named '@Now' under Inbox.

I wish to automate this so that every email that is addressed to me only will be moved to '@Now'.

I tried using rules, but I don't think there is such option ('mail from me, sent only to me'). So I think I need to do it with a VBA script.

What is the code of such a script? (outlook 2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on Email - ***Rules > Create Rule...***

[image]

Or go ***Advanced Options...*** and there is more Options

Start with a blank rule, you can choose whether to apply the rule to incoming or outgoing messages

After you select the conditions to identify the messages that you're looking for, you can select a folder to which to copy those messages

[image]